# Homotopy group of rank 2 of various manifolds

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I have taken a group theory course (undergrad physics), we did in a very short way the superior homotopy groups (to say, 1 hour of lesson) but it was not clear at all, plus we knew nothing of topology so guess how much we have understood...anyway he left as exercise this in the picture. Can you help me with the ones after $S^9$? (We have made no theorems, the only explicit example was $\pi_2(S^2)$ which we calculated).

[image: ex]

Comment: A couple of things, as you are new here:  first off, it would be better to type out the content of the posted image.  Search engines are not very good at images, and there are folk who use this site with screenreaders who won't be able to understand your question as is.  Second, this is an English language website---could you please translate the posted question?

Comment: Ok, got it. The content is basically what i asked in the question, the literal translation is "What is $\pi_2 (M)$ of the following manifolds $M$?"

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an extremely unreasonable assignment to me.

Anyway, $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ a, b \}$ [deformation retracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract) onto a [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) of two $2$-spheres $S^2 \vee S^2$. By the [Seifert-van Kampen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem) this space is simply connected, so by the [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) its $\pi_2$ is isomorphic to its $H_2$. Its $H_2$ can be calculated e.g. by [Mayer-Vietoris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) to be $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, one copy for each $2$-sphere. Kostas' answer correctly describes the intuition but proving it rigorously requires real work; I'm not sure what's being asked here.

$\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \})$, which deformation retracts onto $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, which further deformation retracts onto $S^1$. $\pi_2(S^1)$ can be computed by passing to the [universal cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) of $S^1$, which is $\mathbb{R}$, hence contractible. The conclusion is that $\pi_2(S^1)$ vanishes.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it feels unreasonable also to me because i have no idea of the theorem you have stated.
About the $\mathbb{R}^3 / \{a,b\}$ is it $\mathbb{Z}x\mathbb{Z}$ or the one you wrote? I understand your answer as direct sum, and the one i wrote as tensorial product, so it's different

About the second, yes i had the suspect that it was homeomorphic to $S^1$ by intuition, so the equivalence classes of maps from $S^2$ to $S^1$ is null you say; but you mean 1 as the group with only the identity element or null as no map from $S^2$ to $S^1$? (reasonable,but never seen a 0 at lesson)

Comment: @Dr. Lenz: $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ means the same thing as $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. "Vanishes" means the group is the trivial group, with only the identity element.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ deformation retracts onto the 2-sphere, so the answer is the same. For the next one, although it can be deduced by heavy machinery, intuitively it is $\mathbf{Z}^2$ (like how the fundamental group of the torus is that), because you can have a nonhomotopy trivial sphere around either $a$ or $b$, and you can take linear combinations of them. For the last part, what is $A$?

Comment: Thank you very much; A is not specified but i'm sure it's as the previous exercise, so A is a straight line.
With $Z^2$ you mean $ZxZ$ ? (torus is $ZxZ$, usually i use $Z^2$ for cyclic group).
Btw: in the first two i wrote $Z$ and 1, is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, i edited you comment but i wanted to edit my answer. So, i ask here: With the explicit calculus for simil-torus, how would i proceed? I have no idea on how to do things quantitatively here

Comment: It is correct! You should probably see the answer by Qiaochu Yuan, it is much better analyzed.